# Unable to resolve KeyError: "Index 'slice(None, None, None)' is not valid for indexed component 'MindtPy_utils.objective_value'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyomo

```
import pandas as pd
import random as r
import numpy as np
import glpk
from pyomo.environ import *
from amplpy import AMPL

def pyblock(pyp, pytau, pyr, pys):
  
  
  M = ConcreteModel()
  
  M.m = Set(initialize = list(range(int(len(pyp)))))
  M.e = Set(initialize = list(range(int(len(pyr)))))
  M.s = Set(initialize = list(range(int(pys))))
  
  M.r = Param(M.e, initialize = pyr)
  M.tau = Param(M.m, initialize = pytau)
  M.p = Param(M.m, M.e, M.s, initialize = 0)
      
  M.n = Var(M.m, M.e, M.s, domain=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=0)
  
  def obj(M):
    return sum(-log(1-prod((1-pyp[i,j,k])**(M.n[i,j,k]) for j in M.e for k in M.s)) for i in M.m)
  M.obj=Objective(rule=obj, sense=minimize)
  
  def fire_rate(M, j, k):
    return sum(M.n[i,j,k] for i in M.m) <= M.r[j]
  M.fire_rate=Constraint(M.e, M.s, rule = fire_rate)

  opt = SolverFactory('mindtpy')
  results = opt.solve(
    M,
    mip_solver = 'cplex',
    nlp_solver = 'ipopt',
    tee=True
  )
  # results.write()
     
  return M.n.extract_values()
```

Currently trying to solve this MINLP with pyomo and mindtpy. Parameters are called from R with reticulate. Ipopt solves this with non-integer solutions however I am looking to use mindtpy to provide integer solutions. When I run it, I get the following error:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
KeyError: "Index 'slice(None, None, None)' is not valid for indexed component 'MindtPy_utils.objective_value'"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully run the code you provided using MindtPy on my system, and it resolved your model without issues.

It appears that the problem you're facing might stem from an outdated Pyomo version. I strongly recommend updating Pyomo to the latest release for better compatibility and performance.

On examining your model, I noticed it was a nonconvex INLP (Integer Nonlinear Programming) problem. In such cases, employing the Global Outer Approximation (GOA) strategy within MindtPy can be highly beneficial. Furthermore, considering your objective function includes a logarithmic expression, it's advisable to add a small value (e.g., 1e-6) to the argument to avert any potential computational errors due to log(0). Implementing this adjustment should enhance the robustness of your model.

Hope this helps!